# Does Spark SQL 2.1 support write temp table or hive table to Mysql/Oracle?

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark SQL 2.1,

I am able to read data from mysql/oracle as a temporary view in Spark SQL:

```
val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1"
val user = "root"
val pass = "root"
val sql =
  s"""
      CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW foobar
      USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
      OPTIONS (url '$url', dbtable '(select id, name, now() from db1.company) as x', user '$user', password '$pass', numPartitions '3')
  """.stripMargin(' ')

val session = SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkSQL003").master("local[4]").getOrCreate()

session.sql(sql)
```

My question is whether Spark SQL 2.1 supports to write temporary view or Hive table back to oracle/mysql with pure sql

Answer (score 0):

I post my findings here, Spark SQL supports this functionality in 2.1.0

```
  test("SparkSQL006") {
    val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1"
    val user = "root"
    val pass = "root"
    val sql =
      s"""
          CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW foobar
          USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
          OPTIONS (url '$url', dbtable 'db1.company', user '$user', password '$pass', numPartitions '3')
      """.stripMargin(' ')

    val session = SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkSQL003").master("local[4]").getOrCreate()

    import session.implicits._
    session.createDataset(Seq((100,"IBM"), (200, "Apply"))).createOrReplaceTempView("t")

    session.sql(sql)

    session.sql(
      """
         insert into foobar select * from t
      """.stripMargin(' '))

  }
```